# RPAD not working in SSH Secure Shell

Tags: sql, shell, security, ssh, format

When I use this code, I get two different results:

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD(' ', 30) || 'SPECIALTY IMPORTS' || CHR(13));`

In SQL Developer, it formats the title 'SPECIATLY IMPORTS' in the middle, but when I run the sql file on SSH Secure Shell, it just prints it without pushing it to the middle. Also, if I put spaces in the  beginning of the title, it still doesn't push it in SSH. How do I get the title to format to the center of the page in SSH?

Comment: For starters: The NLS (locale ) settings have to match on the DB server (ssh ) and your windows box.